# :on option in declarative validation in Rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I need to check for password confirmation in a form using the method **validates_confirmation_of** on both **create** and **update** procedures. So we have **:on** option where we can specify **:on => :save**. But, it is simply not working. It is working fine only when I specify **:on => :create, :on => :update** separately on a validation method which doesn't follow DRY aspect of rails. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to validate on both **create** and **update**, then you should not specify **:on => :save**, the validation is for both **create** and **update** by default.

if you want to validate only on create or only on update, then only you should specify :on => :create or  :on => :update